# Behaviour of BufEnter

Tags: neovim, autocmd, plugin-fzf

In `neovim`, open two different buffers as follows (using `:vnew`, for example):

```
*--------------*--------------*
|              |              |
|      1       |       2      |
|              |              |
*--------------*--------------*
```

In the first, run

```
:au BufEnter <buffer> :call feedkeys('ahello', 'n')
```

In the second, run

```
:au BufEnter <buffer> :call feedkeys('ahola', 'n')
```

Then, with the cursor in the second window, use e.g. `:History` from fzf.vim
and cancel the search with `<esc>`.

Doing this on my machine, both autocommands are triggered on escaping the `fzf` window and, even more strange, they are executed in the same pane. Is this a bug, or am I not using autocommands correctly?
End result:

```
*--------------*--------------*
|              |helloahola    |
|              |              |
|              |              |
*--------------*--------------*
```

Comment: `feedkeys` are queued for processing, it doesn't have to be applied to the buffer that triggered `BufEnter`. What really weird here is why `BufEnter` was triggered on `1`  while your cursor rest on `2` after you cancel `fzf`. The problem can be reproduced by quitting any side window that takes full width or height.

Comment: What happens when you add `i` to the feedkeys mode? Like `:au BufEnter <buffer> :call feedkeys('ahola', 'ni')` .

Comment: is there a reason you need to use `feedkeys()`. In general I wouldn't recommend using this unless you know that you really need it. (as mentioned before, it is queued for processing, so it might not do what you want or when you want it).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Would you have a look at the lower part of my [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21556/19763)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Because of [this bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4895) with `norm` in a terminal mode.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use `fzf` and use Vim instead of neovim. So I couldn't reproduce your scenario. <s>Also I was not able to reproduce what @dedowsdi described in his comment.</s>(See end of answer.)

But some general stuff around `autocmd` and `feedkeys`:

Assume we open Vim with three new files in split windows:

```
vim -O a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Vim will open with three windows like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1       |      2       |      3       |
|    a.txt     |    b.txt     |    c.txt     |
|              |              |              |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Move to window 2 and execute `:au BufEnter <buffer> :call feedkeys('ab.txt', 'n')`
and to window 3 and execute `:au BufEnter <buffer> :call feedkeys('ac.txt', 'n')`
then back to window 1.

We now want to move to window 3 using two times `<C-W>l`. To avoid delays with manual input we use:

```
:normal ^Wl^Wl
```

(Note: `^W` is entered as `<C-V><C-W>`.)

So the input queue is `<C-W>l<C-W>l`.

The first `<C-W>l` is consumed and the second window is activated. The autocmd kicks in and calls `feedkeys`.

Now the input queue is: `<C-W>lab.txt`

Now the other `<C-W>l` is consumed and the third window is activated. Again the autocmd kicks in and calls `feedkeys`.

Now the input queue is `ab.txtac.txt`.

This is processed and appends the text `b.txtac.txt` to the first line and leaves you in insert mode.

Conclusion:

Using `feedkeys` is tricky. You should exactly know where you are and what is happening around you. Combined with an `autocmd` this is even more tricky.

While your usage of `autocmd` is correct from a technical point of view, the combination with `feedkeys` might result in unexpected behavior.

---

Now a test based on the comment from @dedowski (using Vim):

> Add an autocmd to 1, move to 3, open a help window, in your case, it 
>   should take full width. exit help window by q, you should see 
>   autocmd of 1 and 3 applied to 3.

Open Vim with three new files:

```
vim -O a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

we get:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1       |      2       |      3       |
|    a.txt     |    b.txt     |    c.txt     |
|              |              |              |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Change to the window showing `c.txt` and then open help with `:help` and we get:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|                   help                     |
|-----------------------------+--------------|
|      1       |      2       |      3       |
|    a.txt     |    b.txt     |    c.txt     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Now execute:

```
:autocmd BufEnter * echomsg 'BufEnter ' . expand('%')
```

Then close the help window using `:q` and Vim will print

```
BufEnter a.txt
BufEnter c.txt
```

(You might need `:messages` to see both echos.)

Well -- that is unexpected. 
.

Comment: Add an `autocmd` to `1`, move to `3`,  open a help window, in your case, it should take full width.  exit help window by `<c-w>q`, you should see `autocmd` of `1` and `3` applied to `3`.

Comment: @dedowsdi Got it - thank you. Updated answer.

Comment: regarding the last part: What is happening is, that Vim will try to put the cursor in the same window, after closing the help window. So what it does it closes the help window. The cursor ends up in Buffer a, triggering a BufEnter autocommand. However Vim knows it has been closing a help window, and therefore tries to restore the window layout it was before opening the help window, therefore moving the cursor to window 2, which triggers again a BufEnter autocommand. This seems to happen specifically for help windows and Vim is just trying to be overly smart :/

Comment: BTW: depending on your terminal width, you might need to use ´:topleft :help` to make sure the new help window will be at the top of the other windows.

Comment: BTW: I proposed a [doc patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/dr27HUmKMY4)